# BetaCV in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

I have a matrix indices with 2 columns and 20 rows.

```
indices = 
[1 2; 
2 3; 
2 1; 
... ]
```

there is a second matrix distMat with 4 rows and 4 columns and i want to find the sum of elements in distMat located in position given in each row of indices[]

```
distMat = 
[1 3 1 5
 2 2 4 2
 3 8 3 7
 3 8 3 7]
```

since indices rows are 1 2, 2 3, 3 1 so elements of that positions should be retrieved and added

so i wrote

```
result = sum(distMat[indices])
```

I am getting syntax error. so how to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach: use [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to build a [logical index](https://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) that selects the values to be summed:

```
indices = [1 2; 2 3; 2 1];
distMat = [1 3 1 5; 2 2 4 2; 3 8 3 7; 3 8 3 7];
result = sum(distMat((sparse(indices(:,1), indices(:,2), true, size(distMat,1), size(distMat,2)))));
```

This [works in Octave](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/My8lMzm1WMFWIdpQwchawUjBGEQYxlpzpWQWl/gmlkCkjBUMFUxBMkYKJiB1xgoWQGwOZwDVF6UWl@aAlBeX5mpANWtoFBckFhWnakDt0bDSMdTUUUDwjIC8kqLSVB2F4syqVJg2sCIUASNNEPj/HwA) as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get the linear indices and then simply index and sum, just like you had at the end -

```
idx = sub2ind(size(distMat), indices(:,1), indices(:,2));
out = sum(distMat(idx))
```

Sample run -

```
>> indices
indices =
     1     2
     2     3
     2     1
>> distMat
distMat =
     1     3     1     5
     2     2     4     2
     3     8     3     7
     3     8     3     7
>> idx = sub2ind(size(distMat), indices(:,1), indices(:,2));
>> distMat(idx)
ans =
     3
     4
     2
>> sum(distMat(idx))
ans =
     9
```